# How do I start a browser in a remote ubuntu system?

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssh, jsch

I am running two Ubuntu 12.04 machines. Machine A needs to start a browser (firefox or chrome) on machine B but it is not required for it to see the browser window. It just needs to start the browser and leave it. I have implemented it using JSch library (code snippet below) but this is the message that is returned - **Error: no display specified**

As a solution, on machine B, I set the **DISPLAY** variable to *localhost:port* or *ipAddress:port* where *ipAddress* is its own IP address and *port* is either 0 or some other number like 10 but it did not help.

The following works from machine A.

```
ssh -X <machine B ipAddress>
$firefox
```

I am running Windows 7 as host and two Ubuntu 12.04 (one 32 bit another 64 bit) virtual machines on Virtualbox with a bridged network.

Code:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
Session session = jsch.getSession(user, ipAddress, 22);
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.connect();

ChannelExec channelExec = null;
channelExec = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");
String command = "firefox -p project001 http://www.google.com";
channelExec.setCommand(command);
String port  = command.substring(20, 21); // which is "1"
String display = ipAddress + ":" + port;
channelExec.setEnv("DISPLAY", display);
//channelExec.setXForwarding(false);

channelExec.setInputStream(null);
InputStream err = channelExec.getErrStream();
InputStream in = channelExec.getInputStream();

channelExec.connect();
```

Any advice? Would appreciate any help either using JSch or anything else.

**Update**: If I update the command to run firefox in the background, it runs, except I cannot bring it to show the browser window.

Comment: What display do you want firefox to appear on?

Comment: When I execute firefox remotely, I do not care what display it appears on as long as the process starts running, but on the machine where it is executed it should show up on the monitor or whatever is the default display device. Does that answer?